# Auto Layout localization warnings from CLI

Tags: ios, localization, autolayout, interface-builder, libtool

I would like to lint on Auto Layout localization warnings which appear in Interface Builder, one such example:

[image: Auto Layout Localization Warning]

These warnings do not seem to surface if you run the Storyboard or XIB through ibtool:

```
ibtool --warnings --errors --notices Main.storyboard
```

Output from ibtool:

```
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.ibtool.document.errors</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>com.apple.ibtool.document.notices</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
```

Is there a way to gather the Auto Layout Localization warnings for the purpose of linting against them?